# How to create a playlist tree view with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I already had a look at `jstree` and `treeview` but correct me if im wrong they are only for a navigation system. I want to create a tree view in a page of content. I added an image of what im looking to do. It is meant to be playlist of podcasts. Can you help me understand how to do this or is there a plugin that can do this? Thanks [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a simple version that fits your needs, it's often a good idea to fiddle around: http://jsfiddle.net/JJAqZ/1/.

```
$('#main > li > *').hide(); // Hide all initially

$('li').click(function(e) { // Open child list on click
    $(this).find('ul').toggle();
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The **jsTree** (jQuery tree plugin) allows to build a navigation tree based on the folder path you provide.

If you want to build a custom tree (not navigation tree), you can use the **[Dynatree jQuery plugin](http://dynatree.googlecode.com/)**, which contains a good set of features to build dynamic html tree views.